# How do I use my /home partition from Kubuntu in Xubuntu?

Tags: filesystem, mount, home-directory

I had installed Kubuntu with separated /home directory (it was on separeted partition).

Now I tryied reinstall it to Xubuntu (was changed only / mountpoint and swap area).

I need use my old /home dir from Kubuntu in new installation of Xubuntu. How I mount this FS to system instead? In FileManager I see it like 10GB filesystem (inside is my home folder and folder structure from my last usage of this)

Thanks
Michell

Comment: While installing, you should have selected the 10GB filesystem with the mountpoint as `/home` If a reinstall is possible, do that. Else, type `sudo cp your/Old/Directory/Path/ /home/michell/`

Answer (score 3):

You will need gparted for this

```
 sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Now DO A BACKUP OF BOTH YOUR CURRENT HOME FOLDER AND THE OLD PARTITION!

ALSO: EDITING THIS FILE CAN SERIOUSLY SCREW UP YOUR INSTALLATION! BE WARNED!

Now you need to run gparted (system -> Administration -> Gparted in GNOME)
Now select your partition, right click and go info. See that UUID? Select it and copy it.
Now open a terminal, and go

```
 sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

At the bottom of the file, add

```
UUID=12265fc6-ee5f-47d4-ba28-dd01532f0b22  /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
```

Noting the spaces. Also, pasting in the terminal uses Ctrl+Shift+V.

Replace 12265fc6-ee5f-47d4-ba28-dd01532f0b22 with the actual UUID of your drive.
Press Ctrl+x then y then enter. Do a reboot. Hopefully you should have all your music and what not there.

Comment: Good guide. foo.

Comment: overkill to install `gparted` only to take the UUID, you can use `blkid` instead. Also, the user should take a chance to remove non partition /home content to save some space, because mounting over it will hide previous content.

Comment: Thanks, but if they are going to have a 10 GB home part they might want to enlarge it a bit later on. Also, I didn't know of any other way (including blkid) in Xubuntu. And I forgot they might want to clear it out too. Thanks.