# Clean Kubuntu 15.04 install - How do I include make my old home partition from 14.04 as new /home

Tags: mount, kubuntu, home-directory

Basically I want to use my old home partition as my new home following a clean install of kubuntu 15.04 over the old kubuntu 14.04 partition. Because of all the data there. I understand that it will have old settings there no longer appropriate  to the new systems. Any suggestions welcome.

I've looked at [How do I use my /home partition from Kubuntu in Xubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39236/how-do-i-use-my-home-partition-from-kubuntu-in-xubuntu)

and I was just wondering if this was still appropriate for 15.04 in April 2015.

Also LassePoulsen's comments at [Mount a directory in another partition as /home directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55239/mount-a-directory-in-another-partition-as-home-directory) suggest a different fstab method (which I can't quite scan into understanding) is that better?

This query arises from a clean install from an iso image on a USbdrive. This followed a failed muon update distribution upgrade from Kubuntu 14.10 to 15.04, in which udisks2 failed to install correctly. I did all this because sound had failed and an upgrade seemed like a possible remedy.... see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/611850/sound-not-working-kubuntu-14-04-kernel-3-13-0-48-generic) for that story.

Comment: Either method will work, the second method is unnecessarily complicated (IMO)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest method I know and use upon every fresh install is:

- start up the live CD with the installer on it (Desktop version)
- mount the old home partition in the install session (via terminal or file manager)
- rename the user directory (`sudo mv USER USER_old`)
- unmount the home partition and do the install with
- manual disk setup: add the home partition as `/home` without formatting it
- after the clean install log into your new system and copy/move all your data from `/home/USER_old` to `/home/USER`
- additional data (mainly configuration files) can be found in the hidden directories (when using dolphin press "ALT+.", in the shell use `ls -a` to list them)
- I.E. KDE configuration files can be found under `/home/USER_old/.kde/share/config`

Works for me, hope this helps...